# Javascript Editors That Test Snippets and Lists variables

Tags: javascript

I am new both to both Stackoverflow and to Javascript, so please do not penalize me too much if some of my terminologies are incorrect.

My programming reference is Matlab that has a script window to write scripts, a command window below to run code and test variables, and a workspace window to the side that displays all variables with their values and their types.

```
 <script>
      var nm = prompt("What is your name?");
      document.write(nm);
 </script>
```

I want to test run the above snippet of Javascript in Dreamweaver, Brackets, Atom, and VS Code. Do these 4 have a command window (not to be confused with the DOS prompt terminal in VS Code) that simply runs snippets of javascript code as it is without bringing node.js into this, and another separate window that lists program variables with their values and types?

How do other Javascript programmers test run snippets and monitor their variables?

Thanks

Comment: You can write this in your browser's web console.  Rather than `document.write()`, I'd suggest `console.log()`. And you don't need the `<script>` tags.  The web console is a javascript interpreter, which it sounds like you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the JavaScript console to test your code in a command-line style interface. To get to it, follow the instructions for the various browsers you may be using:

- Chrome and Firefox
  Right-click or ctrl-click anywhere on the page, and then click `Inspect Element`. From the new window, click on `Console`.
- Safari
  Right-click or ctrl-click anywhere on the page, and then click `Inspect Element`. From the new window, click on `Console`. You can also use the keyboard shortcut `cmd` + `alt/option` + `i`.